# Python error when trying to read csv file in Colab

Tags: python, pandas, csv, unicode, encoding

I need to read the weather.csv file, I have it saved in my google drive and have mounted it with:

```
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/gdrive')
```

Following this the code I am trying is:

```
weather=pd.read_csv('gdrive/My Drive/weather.csv', sep=',', encoding='latin-1', header=None)
```

but I am getting the following error:

```
ParserError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-101-d66270414100> in <cell line: 1>()
----> 1 weather=pd.read_csv('gdrive/My Drive/weather.csv', sep=',', encoding='latin-1', header=None)

9 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx in pandas._libs.parsers.raise_parser_error()

ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 1 fields in line 4, saw 3
```

I have tried it with and without the separator, with and without the encoding and with and without the head but I am still getting errors. Without the encoding the error is:

```
UnicodeDecodeError                        Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-102-258bcb4bc6f5> in <cell line: 1>()
----> 1 weather=pd.read_csv('gdrive/My Drive/weather.csv', sep=',', header=None)

10 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx in pandas._libs.parsers.raise_parser_error()

UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xe3 in position 14: invalid continuation byte
```

The first few rows of data are:

```
Wed 17 Nov 2021 03:20:03 PM GMT, 24.2, 9.8, 35.780, 1, 26.11, 1006.79, 31.14
Wed 17 Nov 2021 03:21:02 PM GMT, 24.2, 9.8, 36.318, 1, 26.22, 1006.76, 31.03
Wed 17 Nov 2021 03:22:03 PM GMT, 24.2, 9.8, 36.856, 1, 26.24, 1006.80, 30.98
Wed 17 Nov 2021 03:23:05 PM GMT, 24.2, 9.8, 40.84, 1, 26.28, 1006.84, 30.91
Wed 17 Nov 2021 03:24:02 PM GMT, 24.2, 9.8, 36.856, 1, 26.47, 1006.86, 30.77
Wed 17 Nov 2021 03:25:03 PM GMT, 24.2, 9.8, 36.856, 1, 26.59, 1006.90, 30.57
Wed 17 Nov 2021 03:26:02 PM GMT, 24.2, 9.6, 36.318, 1, 26.63, 1006.92, 30.51
Wed 17 Nov 2021 03:27:03 PM GMT, 24.2, 9.6, 36.856, 1, 26.69, 1006.92, 30.54
```

Comment: Can you share an example (a few rows) *as text* of your `weather.csv` ?

Comment: Without a sample of the CSV data in `weather.csv` there is really not much that can be said. **Add the data as text as update to question**.

Comment: Apologies, I've added the rows now

Comment: @LouisaWareing, when you added your data did you omit any header lines? It's odd to me that you are getting the error "Expected 1 fields in line 4, saw 3" when the lines you posted have 8 fields. If you had a header with no commas I would expect an error more like "Expected 1 fields in line 4, saw **8**". Another possibility is that that you are pointed to a different file or the wrong folder?

Comment: There are no headers in the dataset, it starts with the first row of data

Comment: I cannot reproduce, this `pd.read_csv('weather.csv', sep=',', encoding='latin-1', header=None)` returns a valid dataframe. I am using `Python 3.9` and `pandas==2.0.1` and `weather.csv` consists of the example rows in your question. What happens if you remove `encoding='latin-1'`?

Comment: I tried all sorts including removing the latin-1, in the end we ran it on a different computer and loaded the file to Colab from their PC (in case it had been broken when sending across) and it now works using - 
weather = pd.read_csv('/content/weather.csv')
which didn't on my PC, it makes me think the file was corrupted at some point. Thank you everyone for your help though!